# How to get object field for LINQ cached object?

Tags: asp.net, linq

In Application_Start i cache some object which i got through LINQ to SQL.

```
    objDataContext objBetting = new objDataContext();
    var testObjects= from element in objBetting.Elements
                   select new { element.attribute };
    HttpRuntime.Cache["test"] = testObjects;
```

On some page i want to read value testObject.attribute. I could only:

```
   var objS = (IQueryable)Cache["test"];
```

**I cache anonymous type of object, how to get properties, maybe it is better question.**

---

OK, i will make and populate object of System.Data.Linq.Table type, and i will cache it, to able casting.

Comment: what? what are you trying to do? I'm confused

Comment: To get values for testObjects.attribute.

Comment: What type of object is `attribute`?

Comment: attribute is string, testObjects is linq result object, which have field attribute(string). I need to read values for attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cache a queryable. They're lazily evaluated, and the chances are high that (1) the context won't be there when you read the cache, so enumerating it will die, and (2) it isn't serializable, so it won't work with distributed caches.

If you have to cache a list of something, put it into an array of primitive types.

Comment: I want to cache object, result from LINQ query, and to read properties.

Comment: You can cache objects, so long as they're serializable. You can't cache queries, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpRuntime.Cache["test"] = testObject.ToList();

IList<string> attributes = (IList<string>)Cache["test"];
```

Comment: I cache whole object, and i need to go through foreach (var o in getObjects), but i dont have o.attribute. This is a problem.

Comment: Your avatar just made my morning.